# How to get a list of all the product URLs from my Magento store?

Tags: seo, migrate

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
```

I am staying with Magento but one of my smaller stores will need to run on Shopify from now. It is already set up on Shopify but I haven't pointed the domain there yet. Regarding the SEO (which we have done a lot of work on) - what is the best practise in this situation?

**Would I export a list of all product URLs (which are likely already indexed in Google) and then set up forwards for these within Shopify?** *And if so, what is the best way to export the list of URLs from Magento?*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest route would be to go with a product export. The URL will be contained in the CSV file generated, you'll then be able to match the URL with a SKU.

Answer (score 0):

All the url of your magento (products / categories / cms pages ) should be in the url rewrite table from magento 2.

From that you need to create a redirection plan in your shopify with 301 redirect (for permanent redirect). From magento url to shopify url. This will tell google that the shopify url is the new url and with time the magento url won't be crawled anymore.

So i would say to create a custom script to extract the url from your magento 2 url rewrite dump and map it with shopify new urls.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Go to your admin panel, and then go to **System** > **Data Transfer** > **Export**

[image]

2. Then, select **Entity Type** as product and you'll see **Entity Attributes** and you can select which field you want to **exclude** from the CSV